# LIST<VIEWMODEL> in view object is returning null in controller mvc.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of class object and which is bind with view like this

```
@model List<Rep.Models.ContactReportSettingViewModel>
var accountArr = Model.Select(x => new { x.AccountId, x.CarrierId, x.AccountNumber, x.CarrierName, x.ClientId, x.ContactId }).Distinct();
```

I have a loop here on var object

```
@foreach (var accountRow in accountArr)
{
  @Html.LabelFor(x => accountRow.AccountNumber, accountRow.AccountNumber, new { @id = accountRow.AccountId })
```

but when I click on save it is returning null or values or not set with the class properties I am accessing this in controller like this:

```
public RESULT method(List<ContactReportSettingViewModel> model)
{ 
  model is null here
  // return View(model);            
}
```

But in model I am getting null. What I am doing wrong?

When I use this

```
public RESULT method(ContactReportSettingViewModel model)
{ 
  // return View(model);            
}
```

Then in model object I can see all the properties but values does not set to those properties

Comment: Please post all of your code, including the View.

Comment: Its `public ActionResult method(List<class> model)` but if its not binding its because you view is wrong. Post your code.

Comment: Make sure you have `[HttpPost]` decorated over the action method

Comment: How you binded model with view? I mean the exact statement on top of your view?

Comment: Show the action/method responsible for creating the View. Are you not sending a null model to the view.  You have to instantiate your model maybe: 
public ActionResult Index() 
{ 
     var model = new yourModel(); 
     Return  View(model);
 }

Comment: bet the list isn't contained within the form that is being submitted. show the code in the view.

Comment: Please check i have updated the question because of some reason I am not able to copy the complete code here it is not allowing me

Comment: You cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls for a collection. You need a `for` loop (the model must be `IList<T>` or a custom `EditorTemplate` for your model.

Comment: And remove the `var accountArr = Model.Select(...)` code from your view. That belongs in the controller, not the view.

Comment: var accountArr this is use to filter the records only

Comment: @Ramanverma. Filter it in the controller! And then use a `for` loop - `for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].AccountNumber) .... }` and look at the difference between this and the html you were previously generating (the `name` attributes) to understand.

Comment: And will you please go to the help files and learn how to format your code!

Comment: @stephenMuecke: Ok let me try this one but when I replace TextBoxFor with LabelFor it is showing the column name not value but if i use TextBoxFor it is showing value

Comment: You can still add the `LabelFor()` as well but that only creates a `<label>` element displays the property name (so when you click on it, it sets focus to the textbox) - it does not create a form control (and why are you giving your `<label>` elements an `id` attribute anyway? - it should be just `@Html.LabelFor(m => m[i].AccountNumber)`)

Comment: Thanks   @Stephen Muecke  its works for me .. how I can make it tick of your answer so that other can see it as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls for a collection because your generating duplicate `name` attributes that have no relationship to your model (and duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html). You can use either a `for` loop in the view, or use an `EditorTemplate` for your model.

Note you need to remove your Linq `.Select()` code and do the filtering in the controllers GET method.

Using a `for` loop in the main view (note the model must be `IList<T>`)

```
@model List<Rep.Models.ContactReportSettingViewModel>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
  {
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m[i].AccountNumber)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].AccountNumber)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[i].AccountNumber)
    .....
  }
  <input type="submit" .../>
}
```

Using an `EditorTemplate`. Create a partial view in `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/ContactReportSettingViewModel.cshtml` (note the name of the file must match the model class name)

```
@model Rep.Models.ContactReportSettingViewModel

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.AccountNumber)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AccountNumber)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AccountNumber)
  .....
```

and then in the main view (note the model can be `IEnumerable<T>`)

```
@model IEnumerable<Rep.Models.ContactReportSettingViewModel>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m)
  <input type="submit" .../>
}
```

In both cases the generated html will include the correct `name` attributes with indexers which will be bound to your model in the POST method

```
<input type="text" name="[0].AccountNumber" .. />
<input type="text" name="[1].AccountNumber" .. />
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following checklist

1) Make sure you added thing binding statement on top of your view

```
@model List<ClassName>
```

2) Then check your is being submitted to the function your mentioned in question and also check the parameter type is same as you mentioned while binding the page.

if you are using html table type structure to display list items then you also need to bind your list with each row. like
for Cell[0][0] bind yourList[0].EmployeeId, Cell[0][1] bind yourList[0].EmployeeName and so on for all the column and then rows by using loop.

Comment: I have added that and because of that I am able to see the list of records but the problem is in the saving only